# R - renv suddently broke and now I can't download any packages

Tags: r, security, renv

I am working on a project and everything was working fine, but all of a sudden I can't seem to download any other packages I've tracked the issue to `renv` and found [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898318/i-cant-install-the-sf-package-when-i-use-the-renv-package-in-a-project) who had the same problem. However, the solution offered is only a work-around and a possible [security risk](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html#downloads).

Here is my error (I removed `ggplot2` and I am now re-installing it):

> install.packages("ggplot2")
>
> Error: package 'ggplot2' is not available

In addition, I get these warning messages:

> 1: could not retrieve available packages for url "https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib"
> 2: could not retrieve available packages for url "https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.2"
> 3: curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation
> function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
> 4: curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation
> function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
> 5: package 'ggplot2' is not available
> 6: failed to retrieve 'https://rstudio-buildtools.s3.amazonaws.com/renv/mran/packages.rds' [error code 35]

I tried to use `renv::equip()` but got this message:

> Error: failed to retrieve 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/extsoft/curl-7.77.0-win32-mingw.zip'
> [error code 35]
> In addition: Warning message:
> curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.

I don't know what happened, I'm not a security expert so any help would be appreciated.

I used to think that `renv` was having problems with AWS, but I tried it in a different PC and it worked fine.

What I want to know is:

- How can I fix the underlying problem so I can normally and securely install packages with `renv` again?
- What caused the issue in the first place (it was working fine before)?

Comment: can you reach CRAN OK? Are you using a proxy server or firewall?

Comment: @monkey Thanks for the interest. I'm not using a proxy or firewall. If I do `renv::deactivate()` I can install everything without any issues.

Comment: Have you tried it again?

Comment: @IRTFM, I did and after using `renv::activate()` I still had the same problem. I was able to fix the issue though with the process described bellow.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the download methods selected by `renv` is non-functional in your environment for some reason. If you need a workaround in the future, you can probably set:

```
Sys.setenv(RENV_DOWNLOAD_METHOD = getOption("download.file.method"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I ever do get this issue again I'll be sure to try it. Thanks again!

Comment: just gets an eroor :  Sys.setenv(RENV_DOWNLOAD_METHOD = getOption("download.file.method"))
Error in Sys.setenv(RENV_DOWNLOAD_METHOD = getOption("download.file.method")) : 
  wrong length for argument

Answer (score 2):

I found this stackoverflow question under the following circumstances:

- I was using Microsoft R Open 4.0.2 but needed to upgrade to Windows R 4.3.1
- I am working within corporate firewalls

I made renv download packages securely by making a fresh renv project and adding the following steps to the project-level ".Rprofile":

- instruct renv to use download.file instead of the default curl:

  - `options(renv.download.override = utils::download.file)`
  - Ref: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/renv/vignettes/package-install.html
- instruct download.file to use "wininet" instead of curl:

  - `options(download.file.method = "wininet")`
  - ref: [install.packages issues behind firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76266237/install-packages-issues-behind-firewall)
- disable MRAN use because MRAN is shutdown (might be optional for you):

  - `options(renv.config.mran.enabled = FALSE)`
  - ref: [https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/mran.html#:~:text=When%20invoking%20renv%3A%3Ainstall,was%20updated%20from%20version%201.4](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/mran.html#:%7E:text=When%20invoking%20renv%3A%3Ainstall,was%20updated%20from%20version%201.4).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue through a combination of 4 actions (I am unsure as which one did the trick):

1. Uninstalled R
2. Uninstalled R-studio
3. Deleted the `renv` folder and the `renv.lock` file
4. Uninstalled my antivirus for good measure.

I then re-installed R, Rstudio, and `renv` and everything was working once again.

Hopefully this will be of use to someone in the same situation in future

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me that i just had too many projects opened, and the memory used by the r session wasn´t enough for installing new packages. Just closed a few projects and it worked!