# How to solve installing of dependencies issue when using renv to share code with collaborators?

Tags: r, collaboration, renv, r-environment, user-environment

I have some script written using R programming language, and for my friends to run those scripts in their own machines without any problems and so that they can get same environment variable as me, I shared with them the renv.lock, .Rprofile, and renv/activate.R files.

However, they are facing some issues in getting the dependencies installed in their pcs. What they did first was set the working directory to the specific project folder, and then run the following commands respectively:

```
renv::restore()
renv::install()
```

And in doing so they are getting the following error:

```
renv::restore()
It looks like you've called renv::restore() in a project that hasn't been activated yet.
How would you like to proceed?

1: Activate the project and use the project library.
2: Do not activate the project and use the current library paths.
3: Cancel and resolve the situation another way.

Selection: 1

Restarting R session...

- Project 'C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/RProjects/the_app' loaded. [renv 1.0.3]
- None of the packages recorded in the lockfile are currently installed.
> renv::install()
- Unrecognized response: please enter 'y' or 'n', or type Ctrl + C to cancel.
- Would you like to restore the project library? [y/N]: y

The following package(s) will be updated:

# CRAN -----------------------------------------------------------------------
- base64enc        [* -> 0.1-3]
- bslib            [* -> 0.5.1]
- cachem           [* -> 1.0.8]
- cli              [* -> 3.6.1]
- commonmark       [* -> 1.9.0]
- crayon           [* -> 1.5.2]
- digest           [* -> 0.6.33]
- ellipsis         [* -> 0.3.2]
- fastmap          [* -> 1.1.1]
- fontawesome      [* -> 0.5.2]
- fresh            [* -> 0.2.0]
- fs               [* -> 1.6.3]
- glue             [* -> 1.6.2]
- gridExtra        [* -> 2.3]
- gtable           [* -> 0.3.4]
- htmltools        [* -> 0.5.6.1]
- httpuv           [* -> 1.6.11]
- jquerylib        [* -> 0.1.4]
- jsonlite         [* -> 1.8.7]
- later            [* -> 1.3.1]
- lifecycle        [* -> 1.0.3]
- magrittr         [* -> 2.0.3]
- memoise          [* -> 2.0.1]
- mime             [* -> 0.12]
- png              [* -> 0.1-8]
- promises         [* -> 1.2.1]
- R6               [* -> 2.5.1]
- rappdirs         [* -> 0.3.3]
- Rcpp             [* -> 1.0.11]
- rlang            [* -> 1.1.1]
- rstudioapi       [* -> 0.15.0]
- sass             [* -> 0.4.7]
- shiny            [* -> 1.7.5]
- shinydashboard   [* -> 0.7.2]
- sourcetools      [* -> 0.1.7-1]
- withr            [* -> 2.5.1]
- xtable           [* -> 1.8-4]

# Downloading packages -------------------------------------------------------
- Querying repositories for available binary packages ... Done!
renv was unable to query available packages from the following repositories:
- # https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/bin/windows/contrib/4.3 --------
error downloading 'https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES.rds' [curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.]
error downloading 'https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES.gz' [curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.]
error downloading 'https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES' [curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.]


- Querying repositories for available source packages ... Done!
renv was unable to query available packages from the following repositories:
- # https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/src/contrib --------------------
error downloading 'https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds' [curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.]
error downloading 'https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz' [curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.]
error downloading 'https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/src/contrib/PACKAGES' [curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.]


Warning: failed to find binary for 'htmltools 0.5.6.1' in package repositories
Warning: failed to find source for 'htmltools 0.5.6.1' in package repositories
Error: failed to retrieve package 'htmltools@0.5.6.1'
Traceback (most recent calls last):
31: source("renv/activate.R")
30: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
29: eval(ei, envir)
28: eval(ei, envir)
27: local(...) at activate.R#2
26: eval.parent(substitute(eval(quote(expr), envir)))
25: eval(expr, p)
24: eval(expr, p)
23: eval(quote(...), new.env())
22: eval(quote(...), new.env())
21: renv_bootstrap_exec(project, libpath, version) at activate.R#1176
20: if (!renv_bootstrap_load(project, libpath, version))
      renv_bootstrap_run(version, libpath) at activate.R#1009
19: renv::load(project) at activate.R#864
18: renv_load_finish(project, lockfile)
17: renv_load_report_synchronized(project, lockfile)
16: restore(project, prompt = FALSE, exclude = "renv")
15: renv_restore_run_actions(project, diff, current, lockfile, rebuild)
14: retrieve(packages)
13: handler(package, renv_retrieve_impl(package))
12: renv_retrieve_impl(package)
11: renv_retrieve_successful(record, path)
10: (function() {
        repos <- if (is.null(desc$biocViews))
            getOption("repos")
        else renv_bioconductor_repos()
        renv_scope_options(repos = repos)
        renv_retrieve_successful_recurse(deps)
    })()
 9: renv_retrieve_successful_recurse(deps)
 8: renv_retrieve_successful_recurse_impl(remote)
 7: dynamic(key = list(remote = remote), value = renv_retrieve_successful_recurse_impl_one(remote))
 6: the$dynamic_objects[[id]] %||% {
        dlog("dynamic", "memoizing dynamic value for '%s'", id)
        value
    }
 5: renv_retrieve_successful_recurse_impl_one(remote)
 4: renv_retrieve_impl(remote)
 3: renv_retrieve_repos(record)
 2: stopf("failed to retrieve package '%s'", renv_record_format_remote(record))
 1: stop(sprintf(fmt, ...), call. = call.)
```

They then run the `renv::diagnostics()` command and the following is what they got:

```
> renv::diagnostics()
Diagnostics Report [renv 1.0.3]
===============================

# Session Info ---------------------------------------------------------------
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8 
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                         
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8   

time zone: Europe/London
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  datasets  grDevices utils     methods   base   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.1 tools_4.3.1    renv_1.0.3   

# Project --------------------------------------------------------------------
Project path: "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/RProjects/the_app"

# Status ---------------------------------------------------------------------
The following package(s) are missing:

 package        installed recorded used
 base64enc      n         y        ? 
 bslib          n         y        ? 
 cachem         n         y        ? 
 cli            n         y        ? 
 commonmark     n         y        ? 
 crayon         n         y        ? 
 digest         n         y        ? 
 ellipsis       n         y        ? 
 fastmap        n         y        ? 
 fontawesome    n         y        ? 
 fresh          n         y        y 
 fs             n         y        ? 
 glue           n         y        ? 
 gridExtra      n         y        y 
 gtable         n         y        ? 
 htmltools      n         y        ? 
 httpuv         n         y        ? 
 jquerylib      n         y        ? 
 jsonlite       n         y        y 
 later          n         y        ? 
 lifecycle      n         y        ? 
 magrittr       n         y        ? 
 memoise        n         y        ? 
 mime           n         y        ? 
 png            n         y        y 
 promises       n         y        ? 
 R6             n         y        ? 
 rappdirs       n         y        ? 
 Rcpp           n         y        ? 
 rlang          n         y        ? 
 rstudioapi     n         y        ? 
 sass           n         y        ? 
 shiny          n         y        y 
 shinydashboard n         y        y 
 sourcetools    n         y        ? 
 withr          n         y        ? 
 xtable         n         y        ? 

See ?renv::status() for advice on resolving these issues.

# Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
                Library Source Lockfile Source Path Dependency
KernSmooth      2.23-21   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
MASS             7.3-60   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
Matrix          1.5-4.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
R6                 <NA>   <NA>    2.5.1   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
Rcpp               <NA>   <NA>   1.0.11   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
base               <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]     direct
base64enc          <NA>   <NA>    0.1-3   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
boot           1.3-28.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
bslib              <NA>   <NA>    0.5.1   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
cachem             <NA>   <NA>    1.0.8   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
class            7.3-22   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
cli                <NA>   <NA>    3.6.1   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
cluster           2.1.4   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
codetools        0.2-19   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
commonmark         <NA>   <NA>    1.9.0   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
crayon             <NA>   <NA>    1.5.2   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
digest             <NA>   <NA>   0.6.33   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
ellipsis           <NA>   <NA>    0.3.2   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
fastmap            <NA>   <NA>    1.1.1   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
fontawesome        <NA>   <NA>    0.5.2   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
foreign          0.8-84   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
fresh              <NA>   <NA>    0.2.0   CRAN <NA>     direct
fs                 <NA>   <NA>    1.6.3   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
glue               <NA>   <NA>    1.6.2   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
grDevices          <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
grid               <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]     direct
gridExtra          <NA>   <NA>      2.3   CRAN <NA>     direct
gtable             <NA>   <NA>    0.3.4   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
htmltools          <NA>   <NA>  0.5.6.1   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
httpuv             <NA>   <NA>   1.6.11   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
jquerylib          <NA>   <NA>    0.1.4   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
jsonlite           <NA>   <NA>    1.8.7   CRAN <NA>     direct
later              <NA>   <NA>    1.3.1   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
lattice          0.21-8   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
lifecycle          <NA>   <NA>    1.0.3   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
magrittr           <NA>   <NA>    2.0.3   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
memoise            <NA>   <NA>    2.0.1   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
mgcv             1.8-42   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
mime               <NA>   <NA>     0.12   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
nlme            3.1-162   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
nnet             7.3-19   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
png                <NA>   <NA>    0.1-8   CRAN <NA>     direct
promises           <NA>   <NA>    1.2.1   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
rappdirs           <NA>   <NA>    0.3.3   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
renv              1.0.3   CRAN    1.0.3   CRAN  [1]     direct
rlang              <NA>   <NA>    1.1.1   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
rpart            4.1.19   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
rstudioapi         <NA>   <NA>   0.15.0   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
sass               <NA>   <NA>    0.4.7   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
shiny              <NA>   <NA>    1.7.5   CRAN <NA>     direct
shinydashboard     <NA>   <NA>    0.7.2   CRAN <NA>     direct
sourcetools        <NA>   <NA>  0.1.7-1   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
spatial          7.3-16   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
survival          3.5-5   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
tools              <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]     direct
utils              <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]     direct
withr              <NA>   <NA>    2.5.1   CRAN <NA>       <NA>
xtable             <NA>   <NA>    1.8-4   CRAN <NA>       <NA>

[1]: C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/RProjects/the_app/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32       
[2]: C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Local/R/cache/R/renv/sandbox/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bd3f13aa

# ABI ------------------------------------------------------------------------
- ABI conflict checks are not yet implemented on Windows.

# User Profile ---------------------------------------------------------------
[no user profile detected]

# Settings -------------------------------------------------------------------
List of 13
 $ bioconductor.version     : NULL
 $ external.libraries       : chr(0)
 $ ignored.packages         : chr(0)
 $ package.dependency.fields: chr [1:3] "Imports" "Depends" "LinkingTo"
 $ ppm.enabled              : NULL
 $ ppm.ignored.urls         : NULL
 $ r.version                : NULL
 $ snapshot.type            : chr "implicit"
 $ use.cache                : logi TRUE
 $ vcs.ignore.cellar        : logi TRUE
 $ vcs.ignore.library       : logi TRUE
 $ vcs.ignore.local         : logi TRUE
 $ vcs.manage.ignores       : logi TRUE

# Options --------------------------------------------------------------------
List of 8
 $ defaultPackages                     : chr [1:6] "datasets" "utils" "grDevices" "graphics" ...
 $ download.file.method                : chr "libcurl"
 $ download.file.extra                 : NULL
 $ install.packages.compile.from.source: chr "interactive"
 $ pkgType                             : chr "both"
 $ repos                               : Named chr "https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest"
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "CRAN"
 $ renv.consent                        : logi TRUE
 $ renv.verbose                        : logi TRUE

# Environment Variables ------------------------------------------------------
HOME                        = C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents
LANG                        = <NA>
MAKE                        = <NA>
R_LIBS                      = <NA>
R_LIBS_SITE                 = C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/site-library
R_LIBS_USER                 = C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/RProjects/the_app/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32
RENV_DEFAULT_R_ENVIRON      = <NA>
RENV_DEFAULT_R_ENVIRON_USER = <NA>
RENV_DEFAULT_R_LIBS         = <NA>
RENV_DEFAULT_R_LIBS_SITE    = C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/site-library
RENV_DEFAULT_R_LIBS_USER    = C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local/R/win-library/4.3
RENV_DEFAULT_R_PROFILE      = <NA>
RENV_DEFAULT_R_PROFILE_USER = <NA>
RENV_PROJECT                = C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/RProjects/the_app

# PATH -----------------------------------------------------------------------
- C:\Users\Lenovo\OriPrograms\Scripts
- C:\Users\Lenovo\OriPrograms
- c:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin
- c:\rtools43\usr\bin
- C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.1\bin\x64
- C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.1\bin\x64
- C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\bin\
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
- C:\php
- C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\
- C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
- C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin
- C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\lib
- C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Migration\
- C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\Library\bin
- C:\Python36-32
- C:\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
- C:\Python36-32\Scripts
- C:\Users\Lenovo\OriPrograms\Microsoft VS Code\bin
- C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\Scripts
- C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\bin\quarto\bin
- C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\bin\postback

# Cache ----------------------------------------------------------------------
There are a total of 37 packages installed in the renv cache.
Cache path: "C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Local/R/cache/R/renv/cache/v5/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
```

My question is how can we resolve this problem? Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you successfully go to https://packagemanager.posit.co/ in a browser on the machine that’s throwing the error? It sounds like maybe a network problem.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for your comment. Yes, I can go to the site succesfully from my friend's pc. H

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73759605/r-renv-suddently-broke-and-now-i-cant-download-any-packages?rq=2 seems to be the same error. Very likely network configuration stuff. renv needs to be able to access the internet to download and install packages.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for your suggestion. The issue is resolved now. Creating .Renviron file in the project directory and adding the following line to the .Renviron file solved the issue 
```Sys.setenv(RENV_DOWNLOAD_METHOD = getOption("download.file.method"))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as suggested in the comments, this problem was solved by first creating `.Renviron` file in the project directory, and then and adding the following line to that file (`.Renviron`):

`Sys.setenv(RENV_DOWNLOAD_METHOD = getOption("download.file.method"))`

and saving it.